# Environment is null when injected

Tags: java, spring

This questions has been asked a few times but they all are using the @Configuration annotation. For what I am doing this is not necessary. I am using the singleton pattern to create a connection to my database. However I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] com.htd.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Exception in com.htd.web.rest.PoResource.generateJobTicket() with cause = null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.htd.config.DataSourceDAO.<init>(DataSourceDAO.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.htd.config.DataSourceDAO.getInstance(DataSourceDAO.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.htd.repository.PoDataSource.<init>(PoDataSource.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.htd.web.rest.util.createJobTicket.<init>(createJobTicket.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.htd.web.rest.PoResource.generateJobTicket(PoResource.java:339) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.htd.web.rest.PoResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cfcd338a.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.htd.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
```

The error is telling to me look at line 24 on my DataSourceDAO class because it is null. It is referring to the following:

```
// Step 1: JDBC props       
    String DB_URL = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url");
    String USER = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username");
    String PASS = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password");
```

Full code:

```
public class DataSourceDAO {

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    private static DataSourceDAO instance;

     java.sql.Connection conn = null;
     java.sql.Statement stmt = null;

    // Step 1: JDBC props       
    String DB_URL = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url");
    String USER = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username");
    String PASS = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password");

    private DataSourceDAO() { }

    public static DataSourceDAO getInstance() {

        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (DataSourceDAO.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new DataSourceDAO();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public java.sql.Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException,
            SQLException {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        if (conn == null) {

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        }

        return conn;
    }
}
```

I am not sure why it would be null. @Inject should work fine, or so I thought.

Comment: Why do you think the field `env` should have a non-null value at the time the constructor is invoked?

Comment: That's a trick question. It shouldn't. But even if it should, why do you think anything should be injecting an object you're manually creating?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you won't get anything injected in a class that you are instancing manually.

After you fixed the manual initialization of the class you should note that inside the constructor you won't have your injected properties available, they're all set after instantiation.

If you want to do some behaviour after instancing the object you should use `@PostConstruct` callback (http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/)

Comment: @Luscas Saldanha I used the "@Inject" thinking this would solve the manual issue. However even if I use "@PostConstruct" I still cannot use the new operator on Environment and I am using the Singleton pattern therefore my constructor is private.

Comment: You know, the singleton pattern can be implemented in a variety of ways. All Spring Beans are by default singletons. If you are planning to use Spring you should let the container handle the lifecycle of it.

Why don't you make your DataSourceDAO a spring bean? You could use the `@Component` annotation in the class. Then you will be able to inject the DAO wherever you want. :)